# Minimal assumption for an elliptic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde

On the disc $\mathbb{D}$ on the disc with a metric $g=e^{2\lambda} \vert dz \vert^2$(let assume $\lambda$ is smooth on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$) and I consider either
$$\newcommand{\Div}{\operatorname{div}}
\Div_g(X)=e^{-2\lambda}\Div_e(e^{2\lambda} X)=f$$
where $\Div_e$ is the classical divergence, $f\in L^2$ and $e^{2\lambda} f$ with zero average and I want a solution $X\in W_0^{1,2}$ with some control like $\Vert X\Vert_{1,2}\leq C \Vert f\Vert_2$.
Or
$$\Delta_g(\phi)=e^{-2\lambda}\Div_e(\nabla \phi)=f$$
with $f\in L^2$ and I want a solution $\phi\in W_0^{2,2}$ with some control like $\Vert e^{-2\lambda} \nabla \phi\Vert_{1,2}\leq C \Vert f\Vert_2$

Those problem are more or less equivalent, and using Gilbard-Trudinger, I know I got **a uniform estimate** as soon as I control the modulus of continuity of $\lambda$, i.e. $C$ depends only of this modulus.
But in my case I only get  $C_0>0$ such that $e^{-C_0}\leq e^{\lambda}\leq e^{C_0}$,
and I would the estimate above with a $C$ which depends only on $C_0$. Does any one have a reference on the minimal hypothesis I can put on the control of the metric, i.e. $\lambda$, to get **a uniform estimate**?

P.S.: In fact I have a bit more $\Vert \nabla \lambda \Vert_{L^{2,\infty}} \leq C_0$, but my question is more about the minimal hypothesis to get the uniform estimate rather than can I apply it in my own case of study.

Comment: In your second question it is not clear what is $X$ and what is the norm $\|\cdot\|_{1,2}$ since you are asking for $W^{2,2}$ solutions. Also note that $\Delta_g\|$ is not well-defined "pointwise" on $W^{2,2}$ functions, unless $\lambda$ has a gradient.

Comment: Indeed, I have edited my question: in fact we can consider $\lambda$ smooth, but I want that the estimate depends only of my Harnack estimate.

Comment: you might want to single out the case where $ \lambda$ is harmonic... i have seen lots of work regarding euqations like $-\Delta u(x) + t a(x) \cdot \nabla u(x) =f(x)$   where $ a(x)$ is divergence free and the goal is to obtain estimates independent of $t$.  One can normally obtain L^infty bounds on u independent of $t$ (maybe with some assumptions on $a$)  but i think Holder estimates are hard to find... try googling 'large advection'

Comment: @Math604, Thanks for your answer, but I realize that the second formulation of my problem had a typo. It is corrected, but unfortunately your answer doesn't match anymore.. thx again

Comment: so now the equation is just of the form $ \Delta \phi = g(x) f(x)$ so you should be able to apply some standard theory to see what you can get?? or is that not sufficient?